# Grouping different values ​into a composite result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that stores colors, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE color (
    id int,
    name varchar(50),
);

INSERT INTO color VALUES (1, 'Blue');
INSERT INTO color VALUES (2, 'Red');
INSERT INTO color VALUES (3, 'Black');
INSERT INTO color VALUES (4, 'White');
```

I need a query to get the results so that both "white" and "black" displayed as "black/white", like this:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Blue |
| 2 | Red |
| 3 | Black/White |
| 4 | Black/White |

I suppose it can be done with some conditional, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it, I had problems with the default. But now it does work as it should.

```
SELECT 
      id, 
      CASE WHEN name = 'Black' THEN 'Black/White' 
           WHEN name = 'White' THEN 'Black/White' 
           ELSE name END as ColorName 
FROM color
```